# Get information from inside tag - BeautifulSoup4 (Python 3)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code is currently pulling information from a table within a webpage, but it's only returning the value between tags. Can someone help me get the email and the name out of the tag that results from this code?

```
emails = []
membership_url = 'http://url/members?letter=a'
print(membership_url)
member_page = s.get(membership_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(member_page.content, 'html5lib')
members = soup.findAll("table")[4]
tds = members.findAll("td")
print(tds)
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
<td><a href="../../options/johndoe--at--gmail.com">johndoe@gmail.com</a><br/><input name="johndoe%40gmail.com_realname" size="24" type="TEXT" value="John Doe"/><input name="user" type="HIDDEN" value="johndoe%40gmail.com"/></td>
```

I don't know a lot about bs4 or HTML so it's lucky I got this far. Ideally, I'd like to pull out both johndoe@gmail.com and the real name "John Doe". All I can get right now is the email from between  the tags.

Comment: is the johndoe%40gmail.com_realname supposed to be altered to also read johndoe%40gmail.com ?

Comment: Yeah, and then eventually I will replace the %40 with @. I don't mind cleaning that data within the script, just have to get it somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the rest of the html here is a possibility for bs4 4.7.1 + that looks for two adjacent `input` tags where the adjacent has a `name` attribute with value `user`. Your mileage may vary with full html. The + is an adjacent sibling combinator.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import urllib.parse

s = '<td><a href="../../options/johndoe--at--gmail.com">johndoe@gmail.com</a><br/><input name="johndoe%40gmail.com_realname" size="24" type="TEXT" value="John Doe"/><input name="user" type="HIDDEN" value="johndoe%40gmail.com"/></td>'
soup = bs(s)
node = soup.select_one('input:has(+input[name=user])')
print(node['value'], ' ' ,urllib.parse.unquote(node['name']))
```